# MS SQL Server PHP PDO Linux nextRowset - ОШИБКА!

Tags: php, linux, sql-server, pdo

в MS SQL через PDO для PHP при мульти-запросе, не возвращаются данные. Привожу условный код:

```
 $stmt = static::$dbh->prepare(' Declare @AccTranz Table (id int,dateCarry smalldatetime);
    insert into @AccTranz (id, dateCarry) 
       select null,null where 1=0; -- Ничего не вставляем в таблицу (where 1=0)
    select 1 as  id, 1 as idName ; -- запрос не возвращает данные
    ');
   $stmt->execute(array());
   $MyResult =$stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,MyClass);
         var_dump($MyResult); // array(0) { } 
     if (empty( $MyResult )) { // if multi-query
       do {
           $MyResult = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'MyClass');   
          var_dump($MyResult );   //   array(0) { } array(0) { }
        } while ( $stmt->nextRowset());
     }
```

Этот же код через PDO PHP под Windows работает без ошибок, последний набор:

```
$MyResult = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,'MyClass');
```

вернет результат  "select 1 as  id, 1 as idName". В SSMS код так же работает без ошибок.
Если изменить запрос:

```
insert into @AccTranz (id, dateCarry) 
   select null,null; -- Что-то добавить
```

Тогда вернется результат "select 1 as  id, 1 as idName". Вопрос: как исправить? может есть какая-то настройка?

Решение такое: в начало пакета нужно поставить **SET NOCOUNT ON;** (для PDO драйвера под LINUX MS SQL):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into @AccTranz (id, dateCarry) 
   select null,null where 1=0; -- Ничего не вставляем в таблицу (where 1=0)
select 1 as  id, 1 as idName ; -- запрос Возвращает данные!
```

Comment: А добавьте в начало запроса "SET NOCOUNT ON;", может поможет

Comment: @DenisRubashkin "SET NOCOUNT ON;" - помогло! Как оформить это в виде ответа на вопрос, и вам поставить "+" ?

Comment: не важно, помогло и ок